# Why is my onSharedPreferenceChangeListener being called multiple times when I change a pref

Tags: android, listactivity, android-tabhost, sharedpreferences

I've written an app with 3 tabs.  Each tab has the same list view with different data sources.  I have setup SharedPreferences in the tabhost activity, but I put my onSharedPreferenceChangeListener method in my listactivity.  When I change a preference, my listener gets called and it updates my database.  This is all working.  However, if I change the data in tab 1, it calls my listener once.  If I change the data for tab 2 it calls it twice and if I change the data in tab 3 it calls it three times.  Any idea why it works this way?  I guess I could setup my shared prefs in my listactivity and that might avoid the issue, but I'm curious why my listener is called multiple times if it's in a different tab.

brockoli

Comment: After some more testing, it seems that if you are reusing the same activity for all 3 tabs, it will call your onSharedPreferenceChangeListener once for each tab up to the tab you are viewing.  So if I'm viewing tab 3 and I change some pref.  It calls my onSharedPreferenceChangeListener 3 times.  Very frustrating.  How can I get it to only call it once?

Comment: Turns out even if you setup your sharedprefs in the listactivity, it is still called multiple times if you aren't viewing the first tab.

Answer (score 3):

You've placed unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() in onDestroy() and it's not called on all activity restarts.

Conclusion is that proper way to do this is to place registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() and unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() in onResume() and onPause() respectively.